# Stuck in "Solving enviroment" when trying to update conda

Tags: anaconda, conda

When I try to update Anaconda, doesn't matter if it is anaconda-navigator, conda, or any action it stays forever saying "solving enviroment" after collecting package metadata. I am unable to do anything. Should I do something? Can I uninstall and reinstall Anaconda?

I tried multiple commands, I tried remove anaconda-navigator as said in the troubleshoot by Anaconda and reset the default config, but nothing worked.

Comment: This is a big reason why experienced users avoid Anaconda and instead prefer things like Mambaforge. The consensus in the community is that having everything installed in **base** is a bad practice and Anaconda becomes extremely problematic when mixing in Conda Forge, despite Anaconda's "blue-sky" documentation on adding packages from other channels. The root engineering problem is that Conda itself depends on a Conda environment and we won't have better user experience until Conda (or Mamba) is a proper standalone executable. Micromamba kind of solves this, but lacks self updating.